# Using IF function or maybe something else

Tags: if-statement

I'm new here.

I would like a formula I can put in excel asking:
If (cell A1) equals Ali then give a result of China,
If (cell A1) equals Beatriz then give a result of India,
If (cell A1) equals Charles then give a result of America,
If (cell A1) equals Diya then give a result of Indonesia,
If (cell A1) equals Fatima then give a result of Brazil,
If (cell A1) equals John then give a result of England,

Sorry if this has been asked before I did a brief search.  Someone did this for me years ago at work but I can't work it out.  I seem to remember him saying its easier to do it in word because the number of brackets at the end of as the formula grows, unless there is another way.  Hope this makes.  Sorry I'm not that good at excel.
Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why not use VLOOKUP instead? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1